# Recurservly initialize the jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add html unit by onclick a button,

```
<div class="unit">
....
<a class="add">Add</a>
</div>
```

in jquery,

```
// add function
$('.add').on('click', function (e) {
.....
});
```

This is working without any issues. My problem is, I'm adding the same html unit and I need to add more units. I know I need to initialize the `add function` again inside the `add function`. Then it is working.

```
// add function
$('.add').on('click', function (e) {
.....
    $('.add').on('click', function (e) {
    .....
    });
});
```

But I have more codes inside the `add function`, So how can optimize it without adding twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), you can delegation event to static parent of element being added dynamically. In your case if .unit is static then you can delegation event to it for `.add`

```
$('.unit').on('click', ".add" function (e) {
   .....
});
```

If `.unit` is not static parent or you do not know static parent then delegate it to document.

```
$(document).on('click', ".add" function (e) {
   .....
});
```

[**Delegated events**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

Answer (score 1):

Then you should probably need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/),

```
$(document).on('click', ".add" function (e) {

});
```

**Note :** i just used `document` to delegate the event, but you should use any closest static parent to the element which is having the class `add`